# Is Servermojo useful to monitor server/website uptime?

Tags: monitoring, website

Is anyone using [servermojo](https://www.servermojo.com/) to monitor its own website/server?

Is it a good (and quite cheap 30 buck / year) way to monitor a **website/server uptime and reliability**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't heard of ServerMojo before however it looks like their offer is pretty basic to fit the needs as to what you are looking for.

I have 2 additional recommendations I would feel are worth mentioning.
Pingdom - www.pingdom.com; great client base and mobile utilities.
& For all of the bells and whistles, without a doubt Gomez www.gomez.com

Most hosting providers offer this service as complimentary for doing business with them if that is where your servers are although I would agree 2 or more helps especially external facing customer responses times.

Comment: pingdom is ineterestingm, difffernet prices, I'm gonna give a try to the free trial. Gomez are useless, they don't show prices, they let me waited on chat for 30 minues before replying and then they said their prices start from 4000€ / year. I think they are crazy.

Answer (score 3):

Servermojo looks like a good standard monitoring service. As Nick said, many hosting providers also offer this service.

If you have a more complex website (like we do) I would recommend one of the newer services that allow you monitor/test your site in a **real** web browser.

We run test macros in Internet Explorer and Firefox every 15 min that test the complete sequence of product search, selection, checkout and credit card payment.

We use [AlertFox](http://www.alertfox.com/), and their support has been great. They also have a useful [free monitoring option](http://www.alertfox.com/free-website-monitoring/), which is a bit hidden on their [plans](http://www.alertfox.com/Plans/) page. The free version gives you one real browser test (and three normal ones).

The keyword here is "real browser monitoring". If you google for that you will find a few other options as well.

Comment: running on Firefox is quite generic, what version of Firefox do they run the test on? Anyway interesting, I'm gonna give a try to that too.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed the plugin but it doesn’t work. It’s tested in the latest version?

Based on this website https://designmodo.com/monitor-website-uptime/ I found more websites to monitor the uptime of my websites. For example, with https://pulsetic.com/ I have created the status page as well.

Can I do the same with this plugin?